# What is the basic working of qtimer?

Tags: qt

I created a rectangle and want it to move with QTimer , I want to know how the methods of QTimer exactly work. This code is running but the figure i drew is not moving.
**.h**
Header file 
     #ifndef WIDGET_H

```
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
 }

class Widget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
~Widget();
private slots:
void update();
private:
Ui::Widget *ui;
 };
```

this is the .cpp file

.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include<QPainter>
#include<QTimer>



Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval(1000);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start();

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
delete ui;
}
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

 QPainter painter(this);

  painter.drawRect(50,80,70,80);

 }

 void Widget::update()

 {
 update();
 }
```

Comment: Your pasted code is not indented correctly, making it hard to read. Please indent the code properly by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

You say "the figure i drew is not moving". In your code, I don't see code for a moving figure, I only see a static rectangle being drawn.

In addition, the `update()` function calls itself, leading to infinite recursion. Remove the `update()` from your code, the base class implementation `QWidget::update()` does the correct thing (scheduling a call to `paintEvent()`), no need to reimplement `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) slot method already has a specific meaning and purpose, you should not override it for other purposes. Further, it is not `virtual`, which tells you it is not even *meant* to be overriden (and doing it can lead to very confusing situations). So rename your own method to... `updateAnimation()` or something.

Then you need to add private member variables for your rectangle position, say `rectX`, `rectY`, `rectWidth`, `rectHeight` (or just single `QRect` if you prefer). Some code snippets help you get the idea:

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
     // default setting is that Qt clears the widget before painting,
     // so we don't need to worry about erasing previous rectangle,
     // just paint the new one
     QPainter painter(this);
     painter.drawRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
 }


 void Widget::updateAnimation()
 {
     // modify rectX, rectY, rectWidth and rectHeight here
     update(); // make Qt do redrawing
 }
```